# recovering from grub rescue screen prompt

Tags: grub

I have got a Grub rescue screen on a CNC machining centre and I cant get the machine to boot up. I have looked up other questions relating to grub rescue can I restore grub without a live cd. When I look that up I typed in ls and the grub screen came up with "(hd0) (hd0,1)" I then put in "(hd0,1)/boot/grub" it then came up with "bios disk read error" I am lost any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

GRUB is the boot loader (the thing that loads the OS.)  If you are seeing a rescue screen it's very likely the drive from which everything loads is failing, making required parts of the bootloader unavailable.  You'll have to contact the company responsible for that CNC system to get it fixed, or get the software (and procedure) to restore it.